# Concepts about Android Drawable

Tags: android

How to get a well understanding the concept of the classes of Canvas,Drawable,Bitmap and Paint? What's the  relationship among them ?

Could someone please give me an example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Canvas class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) documentation:

> The Canvas class holds the "draw"
>   calls. To draw something, you need 4
>   basic components: A Bitmap to hold the
>   pixels, a Canvas to host the draw
>   calls (writing into the bitmap), a
>   drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path,
>   text, Bitmap), and a paint (to
>   describe the colors and styles for the
>   drawing).

So you need 4 components in order to draw something.

1. Bitmap
2. Canvas
3. Drawable
4. Paint

Let's say you want to draw a circle on a background image from your drawable folder.

```
Canvas canvas;
Bitmap mBG;
Paint mPaint = new mPaint();

mBG = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.apple);  //Return a bitmap from the image from drawable folder
Canvas.drawBitmap(mBG, 0,0, null);     //Draw the bitmap

mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);          //Set paint to BLACK color
Canvas.drawCircle(100,100,30, mPaint); //Draw circle at coordinate x:100,y:100, radius 30 with the paint defined
```

Answer (score 3):

[Android's Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html) covers all the details about the API. And best way to learn something is learn by doing, so after reading the docs, [google for tutorials](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&biw=1024&bih=656&q=graphics+programming+in+Android&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=53e9484d3c74b869) and experiment, all your doubts will be cleared gradually.

[Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

[Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)

[Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

[Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)